# Unsubscribe group in scheduled mailings

Tags: civimail

[image: Screenshot of Civi mailing]

I want to send an email to a large group (>50) and have created a smart group for this. Using the scheduled mailing function I selected this group as the recipients but now an extra box appears with an unsubscribe group, what is this for and can I do the mailing without this?

Comment: to be clear I understand your workflow, you started by going to Mailings > New Mailings? ie via /civicrm/mailing/send?reset=1

Answer (score 3):

The unsubscribe group provides a way for recipients to opt out of future mailings.  It isn't possible to send a mailing without this.

Please read the documentation for more information about how this works:  [Mass mailings using CiviMail](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/mass-mailings-using-civimail/#Choosing%20recipients:%20Groups%20versus%20search%20results)

Here's an extract that provides an overview:

> For mailings to search results, you are required to choose a Group
>   from the Unsubscription Group dropdown menu. Here's why: Every mass
>   mailing needs a way to track unsubscribe requests. A simple
>   "unsubscribe" process is required by law in many countries and may
>   help prevent your mailings from being treated as spam. Mailings sent
>   to Groups have this capacity built-in. The next time a mass email is
>   sent to that Group, anyone who has unsubscribed will not be included.
>   However, mailings sent to search results do not have this built-in way
>   to track who has unsubscribed, so you need to provide one.